# What will happen when I remove my Google account from an Android tablet?

Tags: tablet

I got my first tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab A (2017), running Android 7.1.1).  During inital set up, I connected my Google/Gmail account to the tablet.  I have had my Google/Gmail account for years -- using it on a desktop computer -- but I've never had a mobile device before.

I've changed my mind, and I now want to remove my Google/Gmail account from the tablet.  To do this, I am about to follow [the instructions here](https://www.samsung.com/us/support/answer/ANS00078118/) for removing a Google account (specifically, **Apps > Settings > Google > More Options > Remove Account**).  Before I actually do this, I have two questions about what will happen:

**(1) My Google account will be removed from the Android tablet, but my Gmail and Drive files will *NOT* be deleted from the cloud, *correct*?**  I will still be able to access my Gmail and Drive from the web using my desktop computer, as I have always done.

**(2) Will my Gmail and Drive files on the tablet be deleted from the tablet's storage (but, again, *NOT* from the cloud)?**  I would hope that they would be deleted from the tablet's storage, since that is sort of the point of removing the account from the device.  (When I connected my Google/Gmail account, I believe it automatically downloaded much, if not all, of my Gmail and Drive files to the tablet.)

Thanks so much for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1)  Correct.  You are simply removing your Google account from the tablet, not completely deleting your Google account permanently.

2)  Yes and no.  Yes in the fact you will not be able to access information via apps like Google Drive or Gmail any longer, but if you downloaded any files from them for viewing offline (music, photos, documents, etc), those will still remain on the tablet.  You would either have to delete these items individually, or performing a factory reset of the device (which will remove everything), taking it to the state of where it was brand new out-of-the-box.